# English reference for Douady/Grauert construction of versal deformations of compact complex spaces

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, deformation-theory, analytic-geometry

I'm trying to learn about the deformation theory of compact complex spaces. I'm familiar with the case of compact complex *manifolds* from the paper "On the Locally Complete Families of Complex Analytic Structures" by M. Kuranishi. The original references for the case of compact complex *spaces* seem to be the papers "Le problème des modules locaux pour les espaces $\mathbb C$-analytiques compacts" by A. Douady and "Der Satz von Kuranishi für kompakte komplexe Räume" by H. Grauert which are in French and German respectively.

**Are there any English language references for the construction of versal deformations of compact complex spaces?**

Comment: Try [this one](https://ediss.sub.uni-hamburg.de/volltexte/2020/10273/pdf/Dissertation.pdf) as a starter (in particular Chapter 4).

Comment: The title of Grauert's paper should read "Der Satz von Kuranishi für kompakte komplexe Räume".

Comment: Thanks for the correction and the reference!

Answer (score 3):

D. Barlet and J. Magnusson, **Complex Analytic Cycles II**. Unfortunately, the book is not in press at the moment, so you have to wait. While you wait, you can read **Complex Analytic Cycles I**.